# Dictionary Immutable Issue alternative in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Not sure of the best alternative to dictionaries in this scenario - objects or arrays.
I need to change the value of the dictionary(or whatever else) depending on whether the id/key exists, adding to the existing value if the id parsed in does exist, never the key/id - what would be the best alternative?

**Code**

```
Dictionary<int, int> total = new Dictionary<int, int>();
// elsewhere in a function...
ArrayManager(total, id, value);

        public void ArrayManager(Dictionary<int,int> items, int id, int val)
        {
            int i = 0;
            bool found = false;

            foreach(var item in items)
            {
                if(item.Key == id)
                {
                    item.Value += val; // immutable issue stops this from working
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if(found == false)
            { // do something }
        }
```

Comment: you shouldn't be modifying the key of a dictionary.

Comment: All your foreach block can be replaced with a TryGet call

Comment: @DanielA.White - I'm not modifying the key, just the value as stated. Not shown in code (will edit) 'cause I'm a tit.

Comment: @JammAndTea you have `item.Key += val;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to increment the value identified by a given key:

```
public void ArrayManager(Dictionary<int,int> items, int id, int val)
{
    int currentVal = 0;
    if (items.TryGetValue(id, out currentVal))
    {
        int newVal = currentVal + val;
        items[id] = newVal;

        // Do something else
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - won't this do the same as apomene's answer? Is there a benefit?

Comment: @JammAndTea Dictionaries are very fast to retrieve values associated with keys but if you're enumerating over them (foreach) you're loosing all of the benefits

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are trying to do is:

```
if(item.Key == id)
{
    items[item.Key]+= val;
}
```

Comment: do you mean "+= val"?

Comment: Oh, I thought that dictionaries are completely immutable - thank you, will check.

Comment: @JammAndTea They're not immutable, otherwise Add would return a new dictionary and not void